# Get items which are part of the same group in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have a simple data structure of users and events. I am wanting to find all users who are attending the same events that the logged in user is. Users can attend multiple events.

My data is setup as follows

```
{
   events:{
      123:{
         name: 'event1',
         users:{
            9876: true,
            7564: true
         }
      }
   },
   users:{
      9876:{
         name: 'John',
         events:{
            123: true
         }
      },
      7564:{
         name: 'Peter',
         events:{
            123: true
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have the following code to achieve this, I was just wondering if I am on the right path and if my data structure is correct for this type of query (Firebaseref is an Angular factory)

```
FirebaseRef.child("users/" + authData.uid + "/events").orderByChild('displayName').once("value", function (snap) {
    snap.forEach(function (event) {
        FirebaseRef.child("events/" + event.key() + "/users").once("value", function (userSnap) {
            userSnap.forEach(function (user) {
                FirebaseRef.child("users/" + user.key()).once("value", function (realUserSnap) {
                    if (realUserSnap.key() != authData.uid) {
                        //This is a user who attends the same event
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably change that outermost query from a `once('value'` to an `on('child_added'` (and its other `child_*` siblings). The main advantage is that you're monitoring/synchronizing the data, instead of retrieving is just once. An added advantage is that it will remove the need for your first `forEach`.

Aside from that, this looks pretty common. The inner calls need to be `once`'s, because you only want them to execute once. Most people get nervous because of the number of the number of `on` calls that will happen. But Firebase's data retrieval has little overhead after the initial websocket connection has been set up, so this typically performs pretty well.

There are lots of "should", "typically" and "may" in this answer, since the only way to be certain is for you to actually:

- verify that the code functionally does what your application requires
- measure the performance of the code in the conditions that you expect your users to encounter

If you do run into higher-than-expected latency, you could consider denormalizing the data a bit further. For example: you could keep the user's name in each event, where you now store `true`. With that, you would need to look up each user's name.